# Using pipes to synchronize file-writing between processes

Tags: c, linux, fork, pipe

I have something that I've been staring at for most of the night and can't figure out.  I'm writing code in C that is supposed to use pipes to pass a byte back and forth, allowing me to switch between a parent and child process that will take turns writing a string to a file.  Here's my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int fd[2];
int fd2[2];
char token = 'a';
int file = open("output.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
if (pipe(fd) == -1 || pipe(fd) == -1)
{
    printf("Pipe failed");
    return(-1);
}
pipe(fd2);
int pid = fork();
int i;
int j;
write(fd[1], token, 1);
if (pid) // Parent enters here
{
    for (i = 0; i < 100;)
    {
        if (read(fd[0], token, 1) != -1)
        {
            write(file, "ppppppp", 7);
            i++;
            write(fd2[1], token, 1); 

        }
        //usleep(500000);
    }
    wait(); 
}
else if (pid == 0) // Child enters here
{
    for (j = 0; j < 100;)
    {
        if (read(fd2[0], token, 1) != -1)
        {
            write(file, "ccccc", 5);
            j++;
            write(fd[1], token, 1); 
        }
        //usleep(500000);
    } 
}
else // Error creating child
{
    exit (-1);
}        
close(file);
return 0;
}
```

I know the writing to a file works when I don't use the pipes, but now I'm getting an infinite loop and I don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out!  Funny how small things make all the difference.

Comment: Either provide the solution in the answer or delete the question.